# how to send multiple request on a single TCP socket without waiting for response

Tags: sockets, tcp

I am looking for the sample code of TCP socket handling in such a way that I can send multiple request to server without waiting for response of each request from the server. If I set `NO_DELAY` to `1` (to disable `Nagel`) and Set `SND_BUFF` to `0` for forcing data to be delivered immediately, then can I achieve the expected behavior?

Comment: gcc has nothing to do with it, and this is how TCP behaves anyway. It's a lot smarter than you seem to think.

Comment: ^^ what @EJP says.  Just send them, (assuming your protocol can handle the responses when they eventually do get back, possibly out-of-order).